# Converting an odd date format

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a huge table of data where one of the columns contain dates relevant for that specific entry. For all the months except May, these dates come in the format: 'dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm' e.g. '30.04.2013 10:42'. These dates are understood by excel to be dates, which makes table sorting on them straight forward.

However, for May, it comes out as '02-MAY-2013 08:21:03', which Excel doesn't understand. Is there some way to fix this in Excel or via VBA? (I have tried 'Format Cells', with no luck)

Thanks in advance for any helpful input!

Comment: How about Find and Replace (Find: "-MAY-", Replace by ".05.")

Comment: Odd. My Excel understands this as a date and even reformats it to default date formatting like `5/2/2013 8:21`.  In any case, you can do this pretty easily with date functions. I will post a method you can use.

Comment: The find and replace worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume this date is in cell `A1`.  You can put this formula in another cell:

`=DateValue(A1)+TimeValue(A1)`

Then, drag this formula down to autofill the rest of the colum.  Then, copy & paste values over the malformed dates.  You should then be able to apply any date formatting to these values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your method but it returns #VALUE! Are there some settings I could change to make this work?

Comment: Is it possible for you to upload a file with a few of these dates (I only need to see the dates) to Google Docs?

Answer (score 0):

Please try entering `1` in a spare cell, copying that then selecting your MAY dates and Home > Clipboard, Paste, Paste Special with selection Paste All and Operation Multiply.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is with the single quote character not being recognized as part of the date/time combo. You can use a SUBSTITUTE to replace the single quote with an empty string, and then use the VALUE function to calculate the value (which will calculate both the date and time portion of the value)

Use this formula to get the value of the date

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'",""))
```

Then format your cell as a date/time combo